# Sending email from PHP through exchange

Tags: php, email, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, exchange-2010

I figured serverfault might be a better fit for this question. I'm trying to send emails with PHP mail() function. PHP returns no errors and says the email has been accepted whether it sends or not.

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975457/sending-html-emails-in-php-with-mail?noredirect=1#comment46229826_28975457) to my original question on stackexchange.

My web server is connecting to our local exchange server via SMTP. Are there some logs I should check for errors in why messages aren't being delivered? Can I connect to exchange some other way to send email?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (happy to be corrected) PHP's mail() function doesn't automatically generate a `message-id` header line. I wouldn't be surprised if that increased the chances of messages either getting tagged as spam (and so accepted but not delivered to mailbox) or seen as a duplicate (and accepted but suppressed). Sonething like that seems the most likely explanation for messages not arriving in a local mailbox.

You could add a message-id header with code like this

```
$headers .= "message-id: <".$now.".".$rand."@".$hostname.">\r\n";
```

The administrator of your local Exchange service should know where the logs are - message tracking logs will probably be enough.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried adding the message-id and nothing changes. The spam box is a good place to start, I'll have to check on that.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I checked my junk mail and it's all in there. You're the man.